# TABELA SQL RECEBE APENAS UM DOS VALORES DO FORM - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estou preenchendo o formulário e enviando para o banco de dados, porém está dando o seguinte erro:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
> constraint violation: 1048 Column 'nome' cannot be null in
> C:\xampp\projeto_oficina\servico.service.php:22 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\projeto_oficina\servico.service.php(22):
> PDOStatement->execute() #1
> C:\xampp\projeto_oficina\servico_controller.php(15):
> ServicoService->inserir() #2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto_oficina_public\servico_controller.php(2):
> require_once('C:\xampp\projet...') #3 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\projeto_oficina\servico.service.php on line 22"

Para fins de teste, retirei de todas as colunas o "NOT NULL". O erro parou de quebrar a aplicação, porém está passando apenas um valor do form. É como se eu preenchesse apenas um campo do formulário.

[Resultado das colunas sem o NOT NULL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2ulP.jpg)

Pesquisei e vi que um dos erros poderia ser erro de digitação nos NAMES dos inputs, verifiquei e nada. Vi também que poderia ser um erro de conexão, daí verifiquei se tinha feito a conexão direito e também não consegui visualizar um erro. Não estou conseguindo encontrar onde está o erro. Alguél pode me ajudar por favor?!

Formulário:

```
   <div class="container formulario border p-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <form method="POST" action="servico_controller.php?acao=inserir">
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="nome">Nome</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="contato">Contato</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contato" id="contato" placeholder="Ex: 912345678">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-10">
              <label for="servico">Serviço</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="servico" id="servico" placeholder="Serviço">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
              <label for="valor">Valor</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor" id="valor" placeholder="Ex: 150.50">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
              <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label for="situacao">Situação</label>
                <select name="situacao" id="situacao" class="form-control text-center mb-3">
                    <option value="1">PENDENTE</option>
                    <option value="2">PAGO</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center text-center">
              <button class= "btn btn-cadastrar btn-lg">Cadastrar</button>
            </div>
            
          </div>
```

Função que insere os dados no banco de dados:

```
 <?php 
    class ServicoService {
        private $conexao;
        private $servico;

        public function __construct(Conexao $conexao, Servico $servico) {
            $this->conexao = $conexao->conectar();
            $this->servico = $servico;
        }
        
        public function inserir() {
            $query = '
                insert into tb_servicos(nome, contato, servico, valor, situacao)VALUES(:nome, :contato, :servico, :valor, :situacao) 
            ';

            $stmt = $this->conexao->prepare($query);
            
            $stmt->bindValue(':nome', $this->servico->__get('nome'));
            $stmt->bindValue(':contato', $this->servico->__get('contato'));
            $stmt->bindValue(':servico', $this->servico->__get('servico'));
            $stmt->bindValue(':valor', $this->servico->__get('valor'));
            $stmt->bindValue(':situacao', $this->servico->__get('situacao'));
            
            $stmt->execute();
        }

        public function recuperar() {
            
        }

        public function atualizar() {
            
        }

        public function remover() {
            
        }
    }
?>
```

Conexão:

```
<?php 
    class Conexao {
        private $host = 'localhost';
        private $dbname = 'projeto_oficina';
        private $user = 'root';
        private $pass = '';

        public function conectar() {
            try {

                $conexao = new PDO(
                    "mysql:host=$this->host; dbname=$this->dbname", //DNS
                    "$this->user", //usuario
                    "$this->pass" //senha
                );

                return $conexao;

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo '<p>'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Controlador Principal:

```
<?php 
    require "../../projeto_oficina/servico.model.php";
    require "../../projeto_oficina/servico.service.php";
    require "../../projeto_oficina/conexao.php";


    $acao = isset($_GET['acao']) ? $_GET['acao'] : $acao;

    if($acao == 'inserir') {
        $servico = new Servico();
        $servico->__set('servico', $_POST['servico']);
        
        $conexao = new Conexao();

        $servicoService = new ServicoService($conexao, $servico);
        $servicoService->inserir();

        header('Location: index.php');
    }
?>
```

Criação da tabela:

[Criação da tabela](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6czgQ.jpg)

Comment: já tentou verificar o valor da variável `$query` e o que retorna em `$this->servico->__get('nome')` para identificar onde está null?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No seu **Controlador principal**, você não está recuperando todos os campos recebidos.

```php
<?php 
    require "../../projeto_oficina/servico.model.php";
    require "../../projeto_oficina/servico.service.php";
    require "../../projeto_oficina/conexao.php";


    $acao = isset($_GET['acao']) ? $_GET['acao'] : $acao;

    if($acao == 'inserir') {
        $servico = new Servico();
        $servico->__set('servico', $_POST['servico']);
        // Aqui você precisa retornar cada campo
        // $servico->__set('nome', $_POST['nome']);
        // E assim por diante, para todos os campos
        
        $conexao = new Conexao();

        $servicoService = new ServicoService($conexao, $servico);
        $servicoService->inserir();

        header('Location: index.php');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Lucas! Era exatamente esse o problema!!